# Is it possible to have checkbox in dropdown menu in wtform flask?

Tags: flask-wtforms

Please someone help me on having checkboxes in the dropdown list in wtforms flask and i need to select more than one check box and send data to form.Here is my code
#WTform

```
class ReporttestForm(FlaskForm):    
    pname        = TextField("Platform Name",validators=[DataRequired()])
    proname      = TextField('Project Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    collab = SelectField ('Category', choices=[('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), (3', '3'),('4','4')])
    submit      = SubmitField('GENERATE')
```

#HTML code

```
<form method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data action="">
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{{ form.csrf_token }}
  
<div>
{{ form.pname.label }}
{{ form.pname}}
{{ form.proname.label}}
{{ form.proname }} <br><br>
<select id="collab" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
{{ form.submit}}
</div>
```